# Scraping table with <br> in between (does not appear)

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can't get a table from a html with BeautifulSoup. I tryied with xpath, but I don't know how it works... I want to find the lyrics of the song, but it does not appear in "soup". Why? Is it possible to get it with BeautifulSoup? Is xpath the best alternative?

Example from https://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=113. Simplifying my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import urllib

url = "https://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=113" 
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html5lib')
print(soup)
```

I think that the problem lies in < br >, a kind of break.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the lyrics from that page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=113" 

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html5lib')
for items in soup.select_one("table[style='width:100%;margin:0px auto']").select("tr")[:-3]: #kicking out the last three blank rows
    data = '\n'.join([item.get_text() for item in items.select("td p")])
    print(data)
```

Output are like:

```
You can dance, you can jive 
Having the time of your life 
See that girl, watch that scene 
Dig in the Dancing Queen
```